# extract less than the limit value mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i try to display only the articles submitted in the last day, limiting to 5, but i have a problem, if in a category exist less then 5 articles, i don't want to display duplicate, display only that 1,2,3,4 articles, how to do this? Thanks!

```
$Time=time(); 
$LimitDay=$Time - 86400; 
$SelectArticle=mysqli_query($ConnecDB, "SELECT * FROM mk_sn_article WHERE art_category='$Display[CategorieMail]' AND art_data BETWEEN '$LimitDay' AND '$Time' ORDER BY art_id DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: Thanks for interes, i solve the problem, i must put GROUP BY ()

Comment: Then you should delete the question.  Or at least answer the question and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mk_sn_article WHERE art_category='$Display[CategorieMail]' AND art_data > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY art_id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Just use `DATE_SUB` with a comparison - it will pull all -24h articles